# Transpose rows from split_string into columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm stuck trying to transpose a set of rows into a table. In my stored procedure, I take a delimited string as input, and need to transpose it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM string_split('123,4,1,0,0,5|324,2,0,0,0,4','|')
CROSS APPLY  string_split(value,',')
```

From which I receive:

```
value           value
123,4,1,0,0,5   123
123,4,1,0,0,5   4
123,4,1,0,0,5   1
123,4,1,0,0,5   0
123,4,1,0,0,5   0
123,4,1,0,0,5   5
324,2,0,0,0,4   324
324,2,0,0,0,4   2
324,2,0,0,0,4   0
324,2,0,0,0,4   0
324,2,0,0,0,4   0
324,2,0,0,0,4   4
```

The values delimited by `|` are client details. And within each client, there are six attributes, delimited by `,`. I would like an output table of:

```
ClientId ClientTypeId AttrA AttrB AttrC AttrD
------------------------------------------------
123      4            0     0     0     5
324      2            0     0     0     4
```

What's the best way to go about this? I've been looking at `PIVOT` but can't make it work because it seems like I need row numbers, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that row number function will "follow the order" of the string.  If it does not you will need to write your own split that includes a row number in the resulting table.  (This is asked on the official documentation page but there is no official answer given).

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 1 THEN item ELSE null END) as ClientId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 2 THEN item ELSE null END) as ClientTypeId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 3 THEN item ELSE null END) as AttrA,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 4 THEN item ELSE null END) as AttrB,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 5 THEN item ELSE null END) as AttrC,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 6 THEN item ELSE null END) as AttrD
FROM (
  SELECT A.value as org, B.value as item, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by A.value) as col 
  FROM string_split('123,4,1,0,0,5|324,2,0,0,0,4','|') as A
  CROSS APPLY  string_split(A.value,',') as B
) X
GROUP BY org
```

You might get a message about nulls in aggregate function ignored. (I always forget which platforms care and which don't.) If you do you can replace the null with 0.

> Note, this is not as fast and using a CTE to find the 5 commas in the string with CHARINDEX and then using SUBSTRING to extract the values.  But I'm to lazy to write up that solution which I would need to test to get all the off by 1 issues right.  Still, I suggest you do it that way if you have a big data set.

Comment: Thanks Hogan, It looks good. I had to add ORDER BY (`partition by A.value ORDER BY a.value`) to get it working. From your comment, I guess ROW_NUMBER can't be relied upon to ensure the values are in the same order as they were in the string originally?

Comment: @avplol -- I think it can -- that is what the comments on the source page imply.  But as I said the hard, but better way is to parse the line by hand.

Comment: You need an order by in your statement, why dont you have that when you need to sort the data?

Comment: @plaidDK -- Do you mean in the partition by statement?  There is no column to sort by that works.  If I sort by A.value it will be in the wrong order and ROW_NUMBER() will have the wrong value.  We want ROW_NUMBER() to order by the "natural" order.  This is why I made the "follow the order" statement in the answer.

Comment: @Hogan And thats why my suggestion works better than yours. Sorry :)

Comment: @plaidDK -- your suggestion does not work -- every ClientID would be 0.

Comment: @Hogan, like I mentioned in my first comment, I too had to add `ORDER BY` to get it working. It's working well for me. Otherwise, I receive this error: `The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.
`

Comment: @Hogan Again i must refer to my answer. Its working :) And yours is not. But great example though.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got it pretty much answered, but here you can find a PIVOT solution

```
select [ClientID],[ClientTypeId],[AttrA],[AttrB],[AttrC],[AttrD]
FROM 
(
select case when ColumnRow = 1 then 'ClientID'
        when ColumnRow = 2 then 'ClientTypeId'
        when ColumnRow = 3 then 'AttrA'
        when ColumnRow = 4 then 'AttrB'
        when ColumnRow = 5 then 'AttrC'
        when ColumnRow = 6 then 'AttrD'   else null end as 
 ColumnRow,t.value,ColumnID from (

 select ColumnID,z.value as stringsplit,b.value,  cast(Row_number() 
 over(partition by z.value order by z.value) as 
 varchar(50)) as ColumnRow from (SELECT cast(Row_number() over(order by 
 a.value) as 
 varchar(50)) as ColumnID,
 a.value

 FROM string_split('123,4,1,0,0,5|324,2,0,0,0,4','|') a
 )z  
 CROSS APPLY  string_split(value,',') b
 )t

 ) AS SOURCETABLE
 PIVOT
 (
 MAX(value)
 FOR ColumnRow IN ([ClientID],[ClientTypeId],[AttrA],[AttrB],[AttrC],
 [AttrD])
 )
 AS
 PivotTable
```

Comment: Why would you cast row_number() to a string and then compare it to an integer?

Comment: Old legacy code - I just swapped the columns for this questions. Didnt notice the varchar columns - But it works, so i dont understand why i gets downvoted. Somebody doesnt know how to write code. This is working perfectly even if there is a string cast.

Comment: I think you need to test this code -- as written there is no way it "works".

Comment: I'm no expert, but thanks plaidDK, this code works as expected for me.